# Text is not wrapping and is getting of the screen react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have a component which will show a list of items with two `Text` next to each other. one for the title and one for the content. here is my render implementation:

```
let items = [
    {title: 'Test Test:', value: 'Long Test Long Test Long Test Long Test Long Test Long Test Long Test'},
    {title: 'Test:', value: 'Short Test Test Test'},
];
return (<FlatList
        style={{flex: 1, width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}
        data={items}
        renderItem={({item}) =>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}>
                <Text style={{color: colors.accentColor}}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text>{item.value}</Text>
            </View>
        }/>);
```

the problem is text is not wrapped and it's getting of the screen when it's a long text. How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I reproduced your case and I manage to do the correct wrapping by putting a `flex: 1` property on your Long text :

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}>
    <Text style={{color: "red"}}>{item.title}</Text>
    <Text style={{flex: 1}}>{item.value}</Text>
</View>
```

Tell me if it works for you !

Comment: I remember that I tried this with `maxWidth` instead of `width` before posting question but didn't helped. Thanks it's working

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your content in a component that a screen size `width`.

Compute the `width` using the `Dimensions` package.

`let fullWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width`

Then assign this width to a `style` object `{width: fullWidth}`

Hope this solves :)

Comment: Try wrapping your `Flatlist` in a `View` which has a screen size width

Comment: that didn't helped neither